# Python: How to verify sha1 rsa signature with pyopenssl?

Tags: python, pyopenssl

I use this method:

from OpenSSL import crypto

```
cert = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, open('pubkey.pem', 'rt').read())
crypto.verify(cert, sign_code, data, 'sha1)
```

However, when I load the certificate, it shows error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "alipay.py", line 77, in <module>
    qrpay = Qrpay()
  File "alipay.py", line 32, in __init__
    self.cert = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, '123')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 1647, in load_certificate
    _raise_current_error()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 48, in exception_from_error_queue
    raise exception_type(errors)
OpenSSL.crypto.Error: [('PEM routines', 'PEM_read_bio', 'no start line')]
```

However, if I load the public key, it is successful:

```
crypto.load_publickey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, open('pubkey.pem', 'rt').read())
```

Is there anything I have done wrong?

Or if there is any other method to do the verification?

Answer (score 0):

Hope my finding can help people still looking for answers. The issue lies in the file *pubkey.pem*. Even though in many cases public key is the same as certificate the format of the file is different.

To use method ***load_certificate***, the file must start with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`

To use ***load_publickey,*** the file must start with `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----`